# Not standard situation with redirecting subdomain and domain in PHP

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, cpanel, server-configuration

Guys!

I will explain what I want to do. If anyone can help with this, please, give some advices.

I have a website, let's call it http://mysite.com. And subdomain, let's say http://myname.mysite.com.

There is one configuration file inc.php with some personal data each for mysite.com and myname.mysite.com, example ICQ number. All general website files located in mysite.com directory.

I want to be able all general files of the mysite.com at the subdomain myname.mysite.com, in order not to create completely similiar files at subdomain. But with including individual configuration file, located at the myname.mysite.com, containing individual ICQ number.

This is the example how I want this to work:

1. Main domain "mysite.com" has root folder "public_html" with pages: index.php, about.php, articles.php and configuration file inc.php with icq number "111-111". So when serfing "mysite.com" website, you see there ICQ number from inc.php.
2. Subdomain "myname.mysite.com" has folder "public_html/subdomain/myname" with only a configuration file inc.php with ICQ number "222-222". So when going to myname.mysite.com you will see the web pages from "mysite.com" but the ICQ number will get from here "public_html/subdomain/myname/inc.php". And in address bar you will see web pages as:
   http://myname.mysite.com/index.php
   http://myname.mysite.com/about.php
   http://myname.mysite.com/articles.php

So visitors will think that they are serfing individual website myname.mysite.com, but in real, visitors will serf on the mysite.com webpages. So if I change content on mysite.com, this content will be changed on myname.mysite.com.

I need all this staff cause I want to organize affiliate programm with giving personal subdomain name to my partners but with personal configuration file inc.php, that will take ICQ number for consulting.

I guess I've tried to explain what I want to do. God, do hard to explain this situation. Ah, forgot to mention, all this I want to do on PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want changing is the `inc.php` file, I would suggest structuring it slightly differently (the code below assumes only 1-level subdomains, such as subdomain.mysite.com, and some modifications in points (3) and (4) will be needed for deeper subdomains, such as sub.subdomain.mysite.com).

1) In your apache virtual host configuration, define all subdomains to be aliases for the main domain:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ...
>
>     SernarName mysite.com
>     ServerAlias *.mysite.com
>
>     ...
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

2) Have all your PHP files for all subdomains in one directory and point your apache config to that dir.

3) In that directory, create a bunch of `inc` files: `inc.php`, `inc-subdomain1.php`, `inc-subdomain2.php` and so on.

4) Have some sort of `config.php` file, which you include from all other files in your site, and have it contain something like this:

> ```
> if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
>     $host = explode('.', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
>     if(count($host) == 3) {   //have something more than just mysite.com
>         $subdomain = $host[0];
>         if($subdomain == 'www') {     //www.mysite.com is the same as just mysite.com
>             $subdomain == '';
>         }
>     }
>     else {      //if just mysite.com, then no subdomains
>         $subdomain = '';
>     }
> }
> else {  //if no http_host info exists, then assume it's just mysite.com
>     $subdomain = '';
> }
>
> $incfile = 'inc' . ($subdomain == '' ? '' : "-$subdomain") . '.php';
> if(!file_exists($incfile)) {    //if no include file for the requested subdomain, just use mysite.com
>     $incfile = 'inc.php';
> }
>
> require_once($incfile);
> ```

Now, all of this, of course will give you a lot of flexibility, but may not be necessary if all you need is just the different ICQ numbers.  In that case, I would change point (4) code to have only 1 include file, say `inc.php`, and in that file have something like this:

```
$icq_default = '111-111';
$icq_nums = array('subdomain1' => '222-222',
                  'subdomain2' => '333-333',
                  ...);

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $host = explode('.', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
    if(count($host) == 3) {   //have something more than just mysite.com
        $subdomain = $host[0];
        if($subdomain == 'www') {     //www.mysite.com is the same as just mysite.com
            $subdomain == '';
        }
    }
    else {      //if just mysite.com, then no subdomains
        $subdomain = '';
    }
}
else {  //if no http_host info exists, then assume it's just mysite.com
    $subdomain = '';
}

$required_number = isset($icq_numbers[$subdomain]) ? $icq_numbers[$subdomain] : $icq_default;
```

Comment: I posted my answer before reading yours. It is assuring (especially for the OP I am sure) to notice that we suggest very similar approaches.

Comment: @ghbarratt Yes, same things indeed.

Comment: @Aleks G what if I use shared hosting? no access to change vhost configurations. may be there is another variants how to realize it on the PHP level? may be htaccess script?

Comment: @ilnur777 Then how are you setting directories for subdomains?  Is this unix/linux hosting or windows hosting?

Comment: @Aleks G, it is a Linux hosting. I have directory "public_html" where all files are located. All subdomains are created with cPanel in this directory "public_html/subdomain"

Comment: @ilnur777 can you point subdomains to the main public_html as well?

Answer (score 1):

If there is really only going to be one (or just a few) tiny setting(s) that is/are different across subdomains, you should probably consider serving all the subdomains from the same document/web root. Do this with a tweak to your vhost configuration. In Apache it would look something like this (assumes `NameVirtualHost *:80`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias *.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/websites/mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

Then from within your code, you can determine which settings to use (or override) using the subdomain, which might be determined like so:

```
$domain = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$subdomain = implode('.', explode('.', $domain, -2));
```

Then use the `$subdomain` to determine which settings to use.

I am not going to supply example code for how you might determine which settings to use given the subdomain, because your implementation choice is very subjective to your needs.

**EDIT - in response to the question from OP in first comment**

If you absolutely can not put `ServerAlias *.mysite.com` into your vhost configuration then there might still be an easy way to get things to work similarly anyways: Use symlinks for the document/web roots.

So if myname.mysite.com has the document/web root of /var/www/websites/myname.mysite.com and mysite.com has the document/web root of /var/www/websites/mysite.com

Then make /var/www/websites/myname.mysite.com a symlink to /var/www/websites/mysite.com on the web server:

```
cd /var/www/websites/
ln -s mysite.com myname.mysite.com
```

This should cause the files used/served by Apache for myname.mysite.com to come from the same location on the server as those for mysite.com.

**EDIT - for cPanel**

Okay, I am now convinced that [cPanel is lame](http://www.instacarma.com/blog/technical/pointing-a-sub-domain-to-folder-outside-public_html/).

If you already have mod_proxy enabled, you could do this in each root .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/?)(.*) http://mysite.com/$1$2$3 [L,P]
```

Of course this does not even consider requests coming in through https. You could avoid the use of mod_proxy by directing all requests to a symlink in the web/document root for myname.mysite.com, BUT that brings us back to the issue of creating symlinks. It might be easier to get symlinks in the document/web roots rather than making the document/web roots symlinks themselves.

I hope this has given you some ideas. It seems like you will need to do something beyond what cPanel provides to get things working how you want them to.

Comment: what if I use shared hosting? no access to change vhost configurations. may be there is another variants how to realize it on the PHP level? may be htaccess script?

Comment: @ilnur777 See my edited answer. If you want to supply me with details on the directory names on your server I can tailor the answer more specifically.

Comment: I use shared hosting and I'm not allowed to access and change any server configuration. Subdomains will be created too much. As I gave directory in question, I have directory "public_html" where all files are located. All subdomains are created with cPanel in this directory "public_html/subdomain".